# MagicalRecord not returning NSDictionary in fetch request

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, magicalrecord-2.2

Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aMostRecentFlag == 1"];  //  find old records
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [PreferenceData MR_requestAllWithPredicate: filter];
[fetchRequest setResultType: NSDictionaryResultType];

NSDictionary *preferenceData = [PreferenceData MR_executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

I get a warning from the build:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'
```

which indicates MR is not returning the NSDictionary as documented;  is there something wrong with my code? And by the way, nothing is returned by the fetch request, although there is a record that should have been.

Comment: Where do you see it indicates a return of an `NSDictionary`? In `NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.h` Line 23: `+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request;`

Comment: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/229

Comment: I want the one (1) record that is the latest record; it contains all of the settings the user made.  My problem is/was that I can't figure out *how* to get the data out of the array so it matches the order of the attributes in the entity... solve that and I'm one happy camper!

Comment: From what I can see you should be using `+ (instancetype) MR_executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:(NSFetchRequest *)request;` to get just `1` result.

Comment: Not sure that would get me the correct object; that's why I use a flag which I set in the app, which is guaranteed to give me the record I need.  Again, I can't figure out how to get the attributes by name because I'm concerned that they might not be in the order of the CD store.

Comment: Side note on your predicate, if you aren't using scalar values `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aMostRecentFlag == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];'` or `numberWithBool` what ever your value should be.

Comment: As a rule, does CD return the attributes for an entity in the order they are listed in *xcdatamodel*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93625/discussion-between-sbarow-and-spokanedude).

Comment: I fixed the predicate and the record is being returned as a PFArray, which looks like this, which I think is what  I wanted?

  aShopCloses = 2000;
    aShopOpens = 900;
    aStaffPos1 = Kellie;
    aStaffPos10 = "";
    aStaffPos11 = "";
    aStaffPos12 = "";
    aStaffPos2 = Dakota;
    aStaffPos3 = Lori;

Comment: I think thats what you wanted also ;-)

Comment: @sbarow, either will work, but if using a variable, it's better to use @(1) or @(YES).  Those are the current idioms, and they're a lot easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the comments have worked out the answer, but I am not sure that everyone is clear.

A fetch request returns an array of results.  Usually, the objects representing the results will be the class specified in the model.  If you are subclassing `NSManagedObject` (as you should be), it will be the subclass.  If not, it will be a generic-looking NSManagedObject whose properties you access through `valueForKey:`.

However, you can ask for the results to be returned as dictionaries.  This doesn't mean that `executeFetchRequest:error:` method returns a dictionary.  Rather, it means that each object in the array will be a dictionary.

Whichever format you get the results in, you have to pull the object(s) you care about out of the array.  A common idiom is to simply append `.lastObject` or `.firstObject` to the end of the `executeFetchRequest:error:` invocation.  Something like:

```
MyObject *object = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL].firstObject;
```

Magical Record is nothing more than a fancy wrapper around Core Data classes.  It provides convenience methods, but all the usual semantics of Core Data still hold.